I'm getting this error "URL scheme "mongodb+srv" is not supported."
In react.js I'm making a api call using post method but I'm getting error in the console.
Here is my backend code
 const editNote = async (id, title, description, tag) => {
    //api call
const host = 'mongodb+srv://vivek:xyz@cluster0.mdigo2h.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0'

    const response = await fetch(`${host}/api/notes/updatenote/${id}`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "auth-token":
          "xyz",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ title, description, tag }),
    });
    const json = response.json();
}

In frontend there are input fields and a button when a click on button then I get error.


If know the solution kindly tell.
Thanks in advance.

You cannot issue a HTTP request with fetch to the mongodb cluster itself like that. You need to use a client such as the MongoDB Native Driver for Node or Mongoose or Prisma. The host is passed to the driver which will allow you to make queries. I would suggest there is a significant gap in your understanding so take a step back and start here.

Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

You can call an API from a web server using the fetch in your ReactJS web app client and your web server API can access the Atlas cluster.

You also need to mention the name of your database in the connection string after "mongodb.net/" along with the things mentioned by jQueeny.
Example: 'mongodb+srv://vivek:xyz@cluster0.mdigo2h.mongodb.net/"yourDatabaseName"?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0

that's not issue
